# PagerTabStrip setDrawFullUnderline does not work

Tags: android

Calling setDrawFullUnderline(false) still draws the underline.
Also trying to set the color to transparent makes it black.

It can be solved by subclassing PageTapStrip and overriding onDraw and not calling super.
I am also traversing the children to be able to set the typeface.

Is this a bug or default behavior to constrain the component to be consistent with other apps?  I though I saw some code ignoring the alpha values of the underline color.

Comment: Yes it says in android docs under setTabIndicatorColor that "Color to set as an 0xRRGGBB value. The high byte (alpha) is ignored."